# Firebase where condition with orderBy in Android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using this query to fetch the posts by user A and sort by timestamp.

This below query fetches the posts by user A but it doesn't sort by date.

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
    String UID = "userA";
    Query myTopPostsQuery = mDatabase.equalTo(UID).orderByChild("UID");
```

I tried using below query, but it returns an empty set.

```
    Query myTopPostsQuery = mDatabase.equalTo(UID).orderByChild("date");
```

What is the right way to achieve my result?

This is my Data Structure:

```
posts
-KlgYXK01ezPjk
    UID: "YiXgM3qgqcsd"
    date: 1496428200000
    post: "This is a Test Post by user A"
    ,
-KlgYXK01ezPpl
    UID: "YiXgM3qgqcsd"
    date: 1496428220022
    post: "This is another Test Post by user A"
    ,
 -KlgYXK01ezKjk 
    UID: "YiXCWsdj712"
    date: 1496428203000
    post: "This is a Test Post by user B"
    ,
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this may not be the exact answer you are expecting but it helps when your app scales up.

I recommend you use a fan out data structure.

By this create a separate node `user-posts` where you store all the posts by individual users like below:

```
user-posts
-YiXgM3qgqcsd //this us A's UID
    KlgYXK01ezPjket4ery62
        post: "This is a Test Post by user A"
        date: 1496428200000
        author:'A'
        KlgYXK01ezPjket4ery62
        post: "This is a 2nd Test Post by user A"
        date: 1496428500000
        author:'A'    
    KlgYXK01ezPjket4ery62
        post: "This is a 3rd Test Post by user A"
        date: 1496428600000
        author:'A'    
 -YiXCWsdj712 //this us B's UID
     KlgYXK01ezPjket4ery62
        post: "This is a Test Post by user B"
        date: 1496428200000
        author:'B'
```

Now you can query for A's posts lik this:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user-posts");
    String UID = "userA";
    Query myTopPostsQuery = mDatabase.child(UID).limitToLast(10);
```

Since pushing data into a node creates a unique key which are by default in chronological order you don't have to worry about sorting by timeline as you are using `limitToLast()` which gives you posts from the bottom i.e latest

So its better you push data to different nodes `posts` and `user-posts` whenever a user creates a post. This is better as writing data is cheap in firebase as compared to reading data

Now you can just pull out data from ref `"user-posts/UID"` instead of firebase querying data from`posts` filtering all the posts by user **A** then again ordering by timeline which will be expensive and slow if you have many number of posts

When it comes to pushing data to different nodes i.e `posts` and `user-posts` this could be cheap and you can use `updateChildren()` method like below:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
// Generate a new push ID for the new post
Firebase newPostRef = ref.child("posts").push();
String newPostKey = newPostRef.getKey();
// Create the data we want to update
Map newPost = new HashMap();
newPost.put("title", "New Post");
newPost.put("content", "Here is my new post!");
Map updatedUserData = new HashMap();
updatedUserData.put("user-posts/" + newPostKey, true);
updatedUserData.put("posts/" + newPostKey, newPost);
// Do a deep-path update
ref.updateChildren(updatedUserData, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
       if (firebaseError != null) {
           System.out.println("Error updating data: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
       }
   }
});
```

You could refer to the firebase blog post [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html)